# id has autoincrement, but also have another column that increments but not like auto increment does

Tags: mysql

To make this quick : Primary key ID column has auto increment but I also have another column called transaction ID, which is not unique, and can be 1 for 3 rows, then 2 for 4 rows, 3 for another say 2 rows and so on.

Is it ok to get MAX(transaction_id) and ++ ? Somewhere here it was said that there might be a lock problem when 2 or 3 users initiate a new transaction, so they can use same transaction_id. I cannot use AUTO_INCREMENT on this one. Am I right or wrong ?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: I will be using InnoDB style for MySql so as far as I know, it will be row-based lock, not table-based.

Comment: ah, I was worring about what i was reading on stackoverflow about the AUTO_INCREMENT feature (i was using getting the MAX(id) rather than AUTO_INCREMENT) .... and I see that I have other field that won't let 2 users have the same transaction_id...which is good...problem solved

Answer (score 0):

i have another field that describes the owner of the transaction_id...so even if there are transaction_id's with same value, the owner will be different...just worrying too much about the AUTO_INCREMENT feature :)))

cheers